# UITableView Scroll when new cells are added

Tags: xcode, uitableview, scroll

In my app I have a pull down to refresh feature. Basically what this does is it adds some more cells to the top of my UITableView. However when I do this the screen automatically scrolls down. I want to keep my position on the screen when the new cells are loaded.

```
[dataPosts insertObject:[[MainButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 260) withData:0 hasNick:[self createRandomStringWithLength:140]] atIndex:0];
```

dataPosts is the data array of my UITableView. MainButton is a UIView with size 320,260 and it is added as a view into a UITableViewCell. So whenever I add a new entry to my data, the table automatically scrolls down 260 units but I want my position to stay the same. Thanks in advance.

-C

Answer (score 0):

When the new rows are to be inserted you are aware how many rows are going to be inserted. So based on that you can call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method of UITableView to be at the same place even when new rows are inserted at the top.

E.g:
Currently 10 rows are displayed and 1st row is at the top.
Now suppose, new more 20 rows are to be inserted. Insert them without animation.
Now, call above mentioned method with indexPath.row of 21 without animation.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you are looking for something else.